# R-Forge package check error. Package dependencies on linux platform

Tags: linux, r, cran, r-forge

I've got an error regarding to `R CMD check` in R-forge repository. when it checks with windows and mac platform it doesn't give an error except one note which is regarding to maintainer. how ever, it doesn't check correctly regarding to Linux platform and gives me the following error. due to this error I couldn't submit my package to cran. Please help me how to solve the problem.

```
BcDiag log file (check_x86_64_linux)

Sun Dec 30 16:15:16 2012: Checking package BcDiag (SVN revision 7) ...
* using log directory ‘/mnt/building/build_2012-12-30-16-05/RF_PKG_CHECK/PKGS/BcDiag.Rcheck’
* using R version 2.15.2 Patched (2012-12-14 r61333)
* using platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)
* using session charset: UTF-8
* checking for file ‘BcDiag/DESCRIPTION’ ... OK
* this is package ‘BcDiag’ version ‘1.0’
* checking CRAN incoming feasibility ... NOTE
Maintainer: ‘Aregay Mengsteab ’
New submission
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Packages required but not available:  ‘isa2’ ‘fabia’
Packages suggested but not available for checking:  ‘isa2’ ‘fabia’
```

Regards,
Mikeal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be an issue with R-Forge's build server; I have the same issue with another package where a dependency is no longer available but which is available on CRAN and builds/checks OK there. My package checks OK on Linux but not on R-Forge. When I submitted it to CRAN it passed their checks too.

With changes in the last version of R to be released, package libraries have needed to be rebuilt. This may be related to the problems on R-Forge?

Anyway, Suggest you file a support ticket or email the R-Forge team to enquire. If that package builds/checks OK on your own computer, then it is probably safe to submit to CRAN. If you want to be doubly sure, perhaps submit the package to Uwe Ligge's [WinBuilder](http://win-builder.r-project.org/) service to get an independent compile/build/check. If that works OK, then you can be reasonably sure your package is OK to submit to CRAN.

Comment: This is a really annoying problem, and it keeps happening from time to time, sometimes for months until they fix it again.

Comment: @SpammerSlammer Yup; longer term, what with development of r-hub, I see github being the place of choice (it is now for me anyway, and for many others).

Comment: I have a personal preference for svn and against git, but fortunately GitHub supports svn nowadays. I hope this will be compatible with the r-hub extension as well.